# function has stopped working once bootstrap was added to file

Tags: ajax, function

I have a `hash_gen` function that passes a hash number with post to next file. The function is set in operation once the submit button is pressed
delivering text to a var called `parm_x`.

That function is called with:

```
<input style="display:none;" name="parm_x" id="hash_gen">
```

after the submit button. The function is:

```
  function hash_gen()
  {
       var url = "hash_gen.php";
       new Ajax(url, {
           method: 'post',
           onComplete: function(response)
               {
                    $("hash_gen").value = response;
               }

       }).request();
  }
  hash_gen();
```

hash_gen.php works fine.

The function has stopped giving the value once bootstrap elements and validator elements were added.

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default syntax for ID Selector is `$("#id")`.

```
$("#hash_gen").value = response;
```